# Perl get the dir of where the script is being executed

Tags: perl

I am in `/u/meee/ws`
and i am executing `/u/bin/execd`

and

```
use Cwd qw ( abs_path );
print abs_path($0); #gives the location of the script, /u/bin/execd
```

What can i do so that i can get `/u/meee/ws` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Cwd;
my $dir = getcwd;
use Cwd 'abs_path';
my $abs_path = abs_path($file);
```

the first would be it?